# DMLException.getDmlId() returning null

Tags: apex, batch, exception

In a batch Apex class, I've wrapped the DML statements in a transaction and try/catch block, looking for DMLExceptions. When I catch the exception and call `getDMLId()`, it just returns `null`, which is not useful in tracking down the error.

Simplified Code:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope){
  System.Savepoint rollbackPoint = Database.setSavepoint();
  try{
    UpdateRecords(scope);  //Updates existing records
  }
  catch(DMLException e){
    for (Integer index = 0; index < e.getNumDml(); index++){
      this.batchErrorMessage = this.batchErrorMessage + '\nThe job failed for record ' + e.getDmlId(index) + ' on fields ' + e.getDmlFieldNames(index) + '.';   
      this.batchErrorMessage = this.batchErrorMessage + '\nException message: ' + e.getDmlMessage(index);
    }

    Database.rollback(rollbackPoint);
  }
```

Sample message:

> The job failed for record null on fields (My_Field__c). Exception
>   message: My_Field__c outside of valid range on numeric field: My_Field__c

The record is failing during an `UPDATE`, so I know the record id exists.
Why is `getDmlId()` returning `null` while the other methods don't? How can I

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps someone can answer the question of why the method is returning null.

All I can offer is a work-around to use `scope[e.getDmlIndex(index)].Id` instead of `e.getDmlId(index)` in the error message. (With the hope that `getDmlIndex` does not also return null.)

Comment: This worked, but I had to move the error handling into my function call (there are multiple DML operations, so each is in a distinct try/catch block now.)

Answer (score 0):

Encountered with similar problem.

It seems like there is a difference in behaviour when you are using simple `update` statement VS going with `Database.update`. In latter case DMLException really does not return affected record id.

So just switching to ordinary `update` statement has solved the problem in my case, i.e. got non-null id as `exp.getDmlId(0)`.